# Flask Global Variables Disposed Too Early

Tags: python, flask

I am running a flask app with a database. In a test, I have the following setup function

```py
def setup():
    app = create_app()
    init_db(app)
    with app.get_context():
        db = get_db() # should create a persistent db in g

# DB.py
from flask import g
def init_db(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)

def get_db():
    if "db" not in g:
        g.db = create_db()
    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop("db", None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

The problem is, is that the close_db function runs after leaving the app.get_context() context. I prefer having a db which persists throughout the run, and is cleaned up when the app is cleaned up.